# image_rect cropped?

Tags: ros, stere-image-proc, pointgrey, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am having an issue where my image_rect output from stereo)image_proc is being cropped way down to a small section of the center/far right of the image_raw topic. As far as I can tell, I am not feeding these values to rectify anywhere throughout my launch file.

Im using 2 Flea3 Monochrome USB3 cameras in Ubunut 14.04.1 using indigo. To get the cameras up and running, Im using the following package from Kumar Robotics:

https://github.com/KumarRobotics/flea3

In the screen shot you can see that image_raw topic is the entire room, in the image_rect the topic is cropped down to nothing.

https://i.imgur.com/QRrzelN.jpg

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/218634/image_rect-cropped?/) by [theDrGray](https://answers.ros.org/users/24247/thedrgray/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2015-10-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The parameters that are passed to image rectification process come from the camera calibration, and are published on the camera_info topic.

Have you calibrated your cameras yet? What are the resulting calibration parameters?

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2015-10-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [theDrGray](https://answers.ros.org/users/24247/thedrgray/) on 2015-10-05**:
I used camera_calibration, and it seemed to go well. Got a total of 173 samples (went over kill by accident).

This is the yaml for the right camera:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bw2tbkskappKcjFOU281N3Zha1E/view?usp=sharing

**Comment by [theDrGray](https://answers.ros.org/users/24247/thedrgray/) on 2015-10-05**:
I recalibrated for good measure and it opened up he crop drastically. I am now centered and seeing roughly 80% of image_raw in image_rect. Much appreciated for steering me in that direction!

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2015-10-05**:
yeah. very occasionally the calibration comes up with a bad fit, and it needs to be recalibrated.